# YouTube FLV download link

Tags: c#, .net, youtube, flv

What is the current way to download a YouTube video in FLV format using C#/.Net? (if there is any) (the idea is to make it purely desktop based)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "correct" way is to use their published api:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started

**Update:**

You might find this interesting. Here's a class to add missing download support to the APIs:

http://ytdownloadextension.codeplex.com/

Comment: This is the one I am hoping for! Though, as far as I am aware, it conflicts with their ToS, so downloading isn't part of the API?

Comment: The Data API will give you everything you need to create a desktop application to play videos and interact with YouTube. I don't know if they include the ability to download and store the flv files though I wouldn't see why not. I haven't actually messed with the API, I just know it is available. If they don't provide that ability then there probably isn't a "legit" way of doing it.

Comment: No need for a "legit" way of downloading, this is purely a hackaton, just educational challenge.

Comment: From what I can tell the APIs do not provide download support. I updated with a link to a project that attempts to fix that.

Comment: Pretty much what I needed, thank you! Although I'm still fiddling around with doing it manually, but thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Go to youtube.com and open any video then right click on the page and select viewsource search for playerConfig you will see it is assigned with a [json](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), it contains all the infortmation you needed. For further information you can take a look at [youtubeFisher](http://youtubefisher.codeplex.com/) it is an opensource software so you can take a look at the source code and get your required info.

Answer (score 2):

First solution is to use a webservice:

Make a http request (WebClient class is a good one) to http://www.icyvideo.com with the url parameter e.g. http://www.icyvideo.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D2Z4m4lnjxkY

Grep the site for links "Download FLY" and download the movie.

Problem with this solution is that you have to use that website and the location of the links may change. It's very quick to set up, though.

Comment: You gave me a clue how does the link actually work, I just might be able to devise a way to extract it from get_video_info. I'll consider this the answer if nothing handier happens to come along the way. Thanks!

Comment: If this app will be used by many users over the time - use API